Wire an external dual volt ammeter display
I am trying to install a volt ammeter display to Meanwell 3000w CSP-3000 series on the load side. How would the wiring work?

TIA

Do what it says in the volt-ammeter display manual (which you didn't link in your question).

Should be something similar to this https://core-electronics.com.au/dual-digital-display-dc-voltmeter-ammeter-0-100v-0-100a.html

@Randy98 That site provides two schematics to examine. Your voltage is out of range, so you will need the one with a separate power supply for the display unit. What is it about that separate power supply schematic that doesn't work for you?

The link you provided is to a catalogue page. You need a link to the datasheet or installation manual. Any reputable manufacturer will have one. "No datasheet? No sale!" You don't want to get this wrong with a 3 kW power supply. What are you hoping to monitor?
